# How to search in PDF using VBA

Tags: vba, search, excel

Hi I am Rookie in VBA,

Is it possible to search within PDF files using VBA? And return the searched target with the name of the file in which the search is matched?

To give you a better understanding what I do: I have a macro that goes on web page (http://cetatenie.just.ro/ordine/articol-11/) loops through the hyperlinks and downloads the matching criteria files (PDF). Now I need to search within them a name and surname (i.e. BLANARI VITALIE) and know in which file/doc it is published.

The only idea that come into my head is to import data but than again the excel file will get too huge.

Please help!

Comment: to my knowledge you could do so if you have full Acrobat software package. But I base on Excel 2010 while there are some new features in Excel 2013... So, keen to know other opinions

Comment: Maybe you can try something with sendkeys to do Select All (^a), Copy (^c) and Paste (^v)? Or maybe even Find (^f)?

Comment: it can be done, and I found the answer for him on Google, and linked to it rather than copying someone else's work and duplicating it on StackOverFlow

Answer (score 2):

if you have Acrobat Professional installed you can use the Automation (Acrobat.AcroPDDoc) and query the Postscript

Here is an example I found for you (by searching on Google):

[get the data from PDF file into Excel sheet(s) or text file(s)](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1101)

to use this code, you need the below References:

1. AcroPDFLib
2. Acrobat

on my pc they are in:

- **AcroPDFLib**: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroPDF.dll
- **Acrobat**: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.dll

if you can't find them in your VB Editor References dialog, or by searching for in **C:\Program Files\Adobe**, then you don't have the necessary components installed on your pc to *do it the easy way*

The **hard way** is to strip the PostScript and read it into variables then search the variables!

HTH

Philip

Comment: Hey Philip, currently I have in my references only these Acrobat related librarie: Acrobat Access 2.0, 3.0, AcroBrokerLib, and AcroIEHelper1.0. I will try to search other libraries

Comment: Hello Philip, I have issues upon finding these libraries, but do you think it is manageble to do this with ActiveX Function to read PDF?

Comment: well, download and install latest Adobe Acrobat Reader, maybe that will install the libraries you need

Comment: any luck/feedback/problems?

Comment: you should have them installed after you download and install the latest [Adobe Acrobat Reader](http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/) or install full version of Acrobat software

Comment: will try again, many thanks Philip! Surely, will let you know if succeed.

Comment: Sorr, no luck! I cannot figure out yet as nothing worked so far for me. I couldn't find appropr. libraries but I am still searching and update my question if I solve the issue.

Comment: have you downloaded and installed *ADOBE ACROBAT READER* or *ADOBE ACROBAT SUITE* ? These will install the libraries you need I think

Comment: have you tried [Originall DLL: acrord32.dll](http://originaldll.com/file/acrord32.dll/18563.html) or [acrord32-dll-download](http://www.dllfreedownload.com/acrord32-dll-download/)

Comment: I think i did managed to locate it properly in system 32, see what happens after reboot.

Comment: on your c:\ drive, look in this folder: **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\** and this one **c:\Program Files\Adobe\**

Comment: so did you have any luck with my answer yet?

Comment: In the VB Editor References dialog, click browse, and on your c:\ drive, look in this folder: *C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\" and in that folder look for Acrobat\ and in there look for ActiveX* and see what shows up then browse to this one *c:\Program Files\Adobe*

Comment: Hi Philip, if I cannot find these features for Adobe, how can I find them and install?

Comment: on 32-bit windows, after installing **Adobe Acrobat Reader** they should be in the folder above.

Comment: I am with 64 bit...but I assume there shouldn't be huge difference anyway, is it?